# Displaying all attributes on click for features in Map Image Layers (ArcGIS JS 4.24)

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-portal

I am using the ESRI JS 4.24 API to create a mapping application that pulls in a Map Image Layer that is hosted on ArcGIS Portal. I am having trouble getting attributes to show in my pop-up. I would like to display all attributes in the pop-up, not just a select few.

According to documentation the

```
outFields: ["*"]
```

has been replaced with

```
defaultPopupTemplateEnabled: true
```

However, I am getting no content in my pop-up at the moment. Here's what I'm looking at currently:

[image]

Here is my code currently. Any suggestions?

```
require([
  "esri/config",
  "esri/WebMap",
  "esri/views/MapView",
  "esri/widgets/AreaMeasurement2D",
  "esri/widgets/Compass",
  "esri/widgets/Home",
  "esri/widgets/LayerList",
  "esri/widgets/ScaleBar",
  "esri/widgets/Search",
  "esri/widgets/BasemapToggle",
  "esri/widgets/Legend",
  "esri/widgets/Expand",
  "esri/core/reactiveUtils",
  "esri/widgets/Popup",
  "esri/Map",
  "esri/layers/MapImageLayer",
  "esri/PopupTemplate",

], function (esriConfig, WebMap, MapView, AreaMeasurement2D,
  Compass, Home, LayerList, ScaleBar, Search, BasemapToggle,
  Legend, Expand, reactiveUtils, Popup, Map, MapImageLayer,
  PopupTemplate) {

  esriConfig.portalUrl = "PORTAL_URL";

  const map = new Map({
    basemap: "gray-vector"
  });

  const view = new MapView({
      map: map,
      container: "viewDiv",
      center: [-95, 40],
      zoom: 4,
  });
 
  
  let layer = new MapImageLayer({
    portalItem: {
      id: "1acc2c72f17f44b0bd47ca31f63c9a95",
  },

  });
  map.add(layer);

  layer.when(() => {
    layer.allSublayers.forEach((sublayer) => {
        sublayer.popupEnabled = true;
        sublayer.popupTemplate = { 
          defaultPopupTemplateEnabled: true,    
          outFields: ["*"],                   
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

MapImageLayer does not support popup. As the documentation states:

> MapImageLayer...exporting images instead of features

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-MapImageLayer.html

images do not hold features to be displayed in a popup.
You might want to check [FeatureLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html) instead.

Comment: I am able to get pop-ups. The fields just need to be hard-coded.

Answer (score 0):

That's partly incorrect.

The popup is applied to the mapimagelayer sublayers.
If you want to use the default popup template, you can do:
MPl is a defined mapimagelayer

```
for (let sublayer of MPl.allSublayers) {
sublayer.popupEnabled = true;
}
```